# Forces exerted from fluid on a particle in Stokes flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, navier-stokes

Assume we have some small cylindrical particles near a specific point in a laminar flow, such that the **particle** Reynolds number is around unity. Neglecting mechanical interactions between particles, how many forces (except gravity and Brownian motion) are exerted from fluid on the particles and from particles on the flow?

The force calculated from the integration of the flow stress field on the surface of the particle is considered as the drag force. Right? Do we have other forces such as viscous force, frictional force or "**stresslet**"?

Comment: The viscous force is part of the drag force.

Comment: What are other parts?